# Show page publication date in template

Tags: django, django-cms

Im after a way of printing the publication date of a page from djangoCMS. I was thinking something along these lines might pull that information:

{{ request.current_page.get_publication_date }}

Nothing shows with this so i know this isn't right but I was wondering fi someone could tell me if I'm on the right lines or not?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Im after printing a date and time for meta property="article:published_time" for each page of the site I'm working on

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
{% if request.current_page %}
    {{ request.current_page.publication_date }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I have tried this but their is no return on the request?

Comment: Do you have 'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware' in your middleware settings?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this as follows:

{{ request.current_page.publication_date }}

Progressing this i have added styling to the date and time format to get it as I wanted

{{ request.current_page.publication_date|date:"d F Y, P" }}